# Closure in a loop?

Tags: ios, loops, swift3, closures

I'm having some issues with this code:

```
let earlyDate = startDate.dateByAddingHours(-12)
var currentDayInt = earlyDate.daysBeforeDate(Date()) + 1;
var currentDayDate = Podometer.getMidnight(Date());
var currentDayDateServer = Podometer.getNoon(Date());
var wantedDateEnd = currentDayDate.dateByAddingHours(24)

for i in (0..<currentDayInt).reversed() {
   self.getSteps(startDate, challengeEndDate: endDate, wantedDateStart:currentDayDate, wantedDateEnd: wantedDateEnd, completion: { (stepNumber) -> Void in
         self.realmSteps.cacheSteps(user_id: self.user_id, day: i + 1, date: currentDayDateServer, nb_steps: Int(stepNumber))
   })
   wantedDateEnd = wantedDateEnd.dateByAddingHours(-24)
   currentDayDateServer = currentDayDateServer.dateByAddingHours(-24)
   currentDayDate = currentDayDate.dateByAddingHours(-24)
}
```

I am trying to get steps from the iPhone pedometer in a range of day. This is working but the problem is coming from the date in the loop.

They are strangely updated and my caching doing some strange things. I think this coming from the fact that I'm using a closure in a loop. How can I solve it? (if I put a new value in the closure they are not updated).

Comment: It is because your end of three lines might be called before your closure execute.

Comment: You should reuse the date that you send in the closure by return it within your completion closure to update your realm, dont use the variable outside

Comment: @Swift_Guru No changing nothing except more bug

Comment: @Tj3n not sure to clearly understand, i've to return all my date send to getStep closure, and update this return value in the closure body ?

Comment: I mean you send along the `currentDayDateServer ` in your closure as a separate variable, and then return it with `stepNumber ` to update your realm, it will result in correct date

Comment: @Tj3n Oh you'r right ! thank's to you. Clear and solved :)

Comment: Watch out retain cycles calling self in you block :)